# Fetching the complete 'date' field was not coming form 'hr.employee' model

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to get the data from 'date' field that 'date' field is in 'hr.employee' to 'hr.payslip'.I create a function for that task.

Code:

```py
class employee_datecheck(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'

    @api.onchange('employee_id')
    @api.constrains('employee_id')
    def date_check(self):
        if self.employee_id:
            self.t2 = self.date_from
            self.tax 
            product_obj = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('name' , '=' ,self.employee_id.name)])
            if product_obj:
                for products in product_obj:
                    product_new_obj = self.env['hr.employee'].browse([products.id])

                    for tax in product_new_obj.joindate:
                        raise Warning(self.tax)
```

problem is:

The date was not fetching properly i.e it just showing the '2' instead of '2017-09-21'.Please help me.

Comment: what type of field is self.t2?

Comment: 'date_from' is a start date of 'hr.payslip' and t2 is local variable to store the date.

Comment: then t2 is the date you say shows 'a'? ....t2 is a date field, a datetime field, a char field?

Comment: 'date_from' is date field like :'date_from': fields.date('Date From',  required=True) and 'self.t2' is local dummy variable

Comment: ' for tax in product_new_obj.joindate' : in this line I am facing the problem especially in 'joindate' this the date field of 'hr.employe' model.In the place of 'joindate' i tried with many2one field it's working fine.so please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try to print directly the joindate without doing a loop:

```
for products in product_obj:
    product_new_obj = self.env['hr.employee'].browse([products.id])
    self.tax = product_new_obj.joindate:
    raise Warning(self.tax)
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

phani,

1) You code does not look from v8 as tagged on the question, code is v9+ new API.

2) Not sure why are you searching on Model `product` and `employee` because hr.playslp Modle itself has employee field `employee_id` that you can use to get the date. Also, you should not use `onchange` and `constrains` together

Below is sample code:

```
class employee_datecheck(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'

    @api.onchange('employee_id')
    def date_check(self):
        if self.employee_id:
            raise Warning(self.employee_id.joindate)
```

It will be good if you can give more detail for an accurate answer.

Bests